# Easyadmin : display tooltip in index page

Tags: symfony, symfony4, easyadmin

Is there anyway to add tooltip functionality to easyadmin 'index' page?

In documentation, the sethelp function can be used only in the 'detail', 'edit' and 'new' pages.